# Psycopg2: how to deal with special characters in password?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to a db instance, but my password has the following special characters: backslash, plus, dot, asterisk/star and at symbol. For example, 12@34\56.78*90 (regex nightmare lol)

How do I safe pass it to the connection string? My code looks like that:

```
connection_string = f'user={user} password={pass} host={host} dbname={dbname} port={port}'

connection = psg2.connect(connection_string)
```

It gives me wrong pass/username error. However, I tried this combination directly on the db and it works, and I tried another combination on the python code and it worked as well. So looks like the problem is the password being passed weirdly to the connection.

I tried urllib scape, I tried double quotes on the password, nothing works so far :(

Comment: All I had to do was double the backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a reddit thread, I found out that passing variable by variable directly instead of a connection string did the trick:

con = psycopg2.connect(
dbname=dn,
user=du,
password=dp,
host=dh,
port=dbp,
)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to to handle the password having special characters in it.

```
import psycopg2

# Replace these values with your actual database credentials
user = "your_username"
password = "12@34\\56.78*90"  # Note the double backslash to escape the backslash
host = "your_host"
dbname = "your_dbname"
port = "your_port"

# Escape the password and construct the connection string
escaped_password = password.replace("'", "''")  # Replace single quotes with double single quotes
connection_string = f"user={user} password='{escaped_password}' host={host} dbname={dbname} port={port}"

# Establish the database connection
connection = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)

# Now you can use the 'connection' object to interact with the database
```

Answer (score 0):

As [jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes) mentioned in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77184491/psycopg2-how-to-deal-with-special-characters-in-password#comment136069415_77184491), in this particular case it's sufficient to double the backslash to escape it:

```py
password = '12@34\\56.78*90'
```

since you are hardcoding the password in your script (just for testing, right?), you could also use a raw string to automatically escape the backslash:

```py
password = r'12@34\56.78*90'
```

Embedded quotes can be escaped or replaced (as in [Maimoona Abid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22213656/maimoona-abid)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77185081/5320906)), but it may be simpler to quote the string with double quotes if the password contains a single quote, and vice-versa, or use triple quotes:

```py
password = r"12@34\56.78*9'0"
password = r'''12@34\56.78*9'0'''
```

PostgreSQL also supports reading passwords from the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable, and psycopg2 seems to support this directly (though it does not seem to be documented). If `PGPASSWORD` is defined it is not necessary to pass `password` to `psycopg2.connect()`.

If the password is stored in the environment it must be escaped according to the shell's quoting rules, for example in bash:

```bash
PGPASSWORD='12@34\56.78*9'\''0' python myscript.py
```

PostgreSQL also supports storing the password in a file, by default in ${HOME}/.pgpass but definable by the env var `PGPASSFILE`. Psycopg2 does not support this directly, but you can read the file in your code:
If stored in a file no escaping is necessary, (but don't forget to strip the end of line character when reading):

```bash
$ cat .pgpass
localhost:5432:test:souser:12@34\56.78*9'0
PGPASSFILE=path/to/.pgpass python myscript.py
```

PostgreSQL also supports connecting using a URI. In this case the password may need to be percent-encoded:

```
from urllib import parse
import psycopg2

dsn = fr'postgresql://souser:{parse.quote(password)}@localhost/test'

with psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn) as conn:
    ...
```

All of the above methods also work for `psycopg.connect()`.

A sample test script:

```py
import os
import psycopg2

if os.getenv('PGPASSWORD'):
    # psycopg22 will use the env var automatically, no need to specify it here.
    password = None
elif password_file := os.getenv('PGPASSFILE'):
    with open(password_file) as f:
        line = next(f)
        *_, password = line.rpartition(':')
        password = password.strip()
else:
    password = r"12@34\56.78*9'0"

conn_data = dict(user='souser', dbname='test', host='localhost', port=5432)
if password is not None:
    conn_data['password'] = password

with psycopg2.connect(**conn_data) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("""SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 2""")
        assert cur.fetchone() is None
conn.close()
```